# MySQL optimize query against table containing 13M records

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization

I recently started working with a legacy Rails application. Trying to go through with some of the queries used to get analytics related data. Some table contains around 13M records. Running count query against these table itself takes more than a minute. The query against which I am trying to run explain and analyze is taking more than 30 min.

Query

```sql
    
    SELECT
       portfolio_id,
       min(order_trigger_date) as order_trigger_date 
    FROM
       `user_orders` 
       INNER JOIN
          `user_portfolios` 
          ON `user_portfolios`.`id` = `user_orders`.`portfolio_id` 
    WHERE
       `user_orders`.`state` IN 
       (
          'executed_success',
          'executed_failure',
          'placed_failure'
       )
       AND `user_orders`.`type` = 'buy' 
       AND `user_orders`.`order_trigger_date` BETWEEN '1969-12-31 18:30:00' AND '2023-12-15 18:29:59' 
       AND `user_portfolios`.`state` = 'active' 
    GROUP BY
       `user_orders`.`portfolio_id`
```

We have proper indexes in both the tables

```
user_order
  - state
  - type
  - order_trigger_date
  - portfolio_id

user_portfolios 
  - state
```

Below is the explain result

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type        | possible_keys                                                                                                                        | key                                                                     | key_len | ref                             | rows    | filtered | Extra                                                                                                                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_orders     | NULL       | index_merge | index_user_orders_on_state,index_user_orders_on_type,index_user_orders_on_portfolio_id,index_order_trigger_date_on_admin_user_orders | index_user_orders_on_type,index_order_trigger_date_on_admin_user_orders | 513,6   | NULL                            | 3100629 |    66.09 | Using intersect(index_user_orders_on_type,index_order_trigger_date_on_admin_user_orders); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_portfolios | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,index_state_on_user_portfolios                                                                                               | PRIMARY                                                                 | 8       | mydb.user_orders.portfolio_id |       1 |     50.0 | Using where                                                                                                                            |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Can anyone suggest me any ways to optimize the above query? What are the alternative methods/ways I can use to fetch this data in faster manner?

Be

Comment: What does the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` say?

Answer (score 2):

> We have proper indexes in both the tables

In my experience I have never seen MySQL using more than one index per table , so you need a multicolumn index in this case.

---

Add the following indexes, try again the query and see the execution plan.

user_orders

```
alter table user_orders 
 add index pid_tp_ortridt_st (portfolio_id,type,order_trigger_date,state) ;
```

user_portfolios

```
alter table user_portfolios 
  add index id_st (id,state) ;
```

See [Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's a nasty.  You are filtering on two tables, and the main table needs a two-dimensional index (which does not exist).

I suggest these as possibly helping:

```
user_orders:  INDEX(type, state, order_trigger_date, portfolio_id)
user_orders:  INDEX(type, order_trigger_date, portfolio_id, state)
user_portfolios:  INDEX(state, id)
```

You could try this reformulation, too:

```
SELECT  uo.portfolio_id, min(uo.order_trigger_date) as order_trigger_date
    FROM  `user_orders` AS uo `user_portfolios` AS up  ON up.`id` = uo.`portfolio_id`
    WHERE  uo.`state` IN ( 'executed_success', 
                           'executed_failure',
                           'placed_failure' 
                         )
      AND  uo.`type` = 'buy'
      AND  uo.`order_trigger_date` BETWEEN '1969-12-31 18:30:00' AND '2023-12-15 18:29:59'
      AND  up.`state` = 'active'
      AND  EXISTS  ( SELECT  1
            FROM  `user_portfolios` AS up
            WHERE  up.`id` = uo.`portfolio_id` 
                   )
    GROUP BY  uo.`portfolio_id`
```

The following won't change speed, but makes more sense:

```
 AND `order_trigger_date` BETWEEN '1969-12-31 18:30:00'
                              AND '2023-12-15 18:29:59'
```

-->

```
 AND `order_trigger_date` < '2023-12-15 18:29:59'
```

That looks like it is "all dates", in which case remove that part of the WHERE clause to make any SELECT variant run faster.  If date range comes from user input, build the WHERE clause on the fly to avoid kludges like that BETWEEN.